# Ember Array binding not updating

Tags: arrays, ember.js

I have an array in which I'm adding elements. Then, in the template, all the elements are being displayed. The issue is that only the first time an element is added to array, only then the template is being added, afterwards, whenever an element is added to the template, the template is not updating though the element is properly being inserted into the array.

How to make the template update every time the content of the array changes?

A worked example on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/pamequ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ember to properly react to changes to your `selectedTags` array, you need to use

`selectedTags.pushObject(tag);`

instead of

`selectedTags.push(tag);`

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/mixufu/1/edit?html,js,output)

More on `pushObject` [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject)